# BlackBerry RIMAPPSA2 signing key required -- why?

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to sign our BlackBerry app, but now it's asking for "RIMAPPSA2" signing key, which is the signing key for private APIs (which isn't allowed in the app world I assume). So I want to remove this requirement so I can actually run the app on devices.

There's nothing in the build log. My app does NOT use any of the following packages (which the internet suggests might be the issue):

- net.rim.vm.Persistable
- net.rim.vm.*
- net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.*
- net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.debug.*
- net.rim.device.api.script.*
- org.w3c.dom.jsp2.*   <- actually is uses org.w3c.dom.*, but I've had an app not require this that already had this package in it.
- net.rim.device.api.io.Seekable

And I'm not importing any external JARs (although I was before). I'm using the 4.5 JDE.

How can I find out what is making the signer tool require this signature?

Is there any way to track down what is causing this signature (RIMAPPSA2) to be required?

Comment: Have you find out why RIMAPPSA2 is required ?

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to a bug in Eclipse or RIM. You might not be using the RIMAPPSA2 classes.

OK, so its hard to believe but this page might fix the problem for some:

- [Frustrations with Blackberry Developer plugins for Eclipse](http://www.michaelquattlebaum.com/?p=243&cpage=1)

Basically its a bug, and by changing the Application Descriptor, saving, removing & re-adding the JAR file, the problem is fixed.

### Follow-up #1 - might not work:

The above solution enabled me to build & sign the app. Unfortunately the app won't run on the phone `Module 'MyApp" attempts to access a secure API.`

### Follow-up #2 - this worked for me:

I documented a full solution that worked for me here:

- [BlackBerry - use own JAR file in own project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9978353/383414)

In my case, I was importing my own JAR file, and I needed to set that project's build type to be a `MIDLET`. Setting it as `LIBRARY` or `APPLICATION` caused problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it, as I am waiting for my signing key.

If you use eclipse, you can have following settings that can be turned off.

[image]