# Is there a list of classes, methods and API which will trigger RIMAPPSA2 permission when signing Blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, signing

I understand why RIMAPPSA2 permission is thrown when signing a BlackBerry application. However, I don't know which classes, functions and/or API requires such permission.

Is there any way to find out (or better a documentation listing that information) ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RIMAPPSA2 permission is required when dealing with Blackberry Controlled APIs.** In this particular case, **I was definining new classes and redefining existing classes in one of the packages part of the Blackberry Controlled APIs.**

Moving my classes to package not controlled by Blackberry Controlled APIs solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved a similar problem for myself. As per my answer on [BlackBerry RIMAPPSA2 signing key required — why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976284/383414). I have updated this answer to help in case of future searches on similar words...

---

This might be due to a bug in Eclipse or RIM. You might not be using the RIMAPPSA2 classes.

OK, so its hard to believe but this page might fix the problem for some:

- [Frustrations with Blackberry Developer plugins for Eclipse](http://www.michaelquattlebaum.com/?p=243&cpage=1)

Basically its a bug, and by changing the Application Descriptor, saving, removing & re-adding the JAR file, the problem is fixed.

### Follow-up #1 - might not work:

The above solution enabled me to build & sign the app. Unfortunately the app won't run on the phone `Module 'MyApp" attempts to access a secure API.`

### Follow-up #2 - this worked for me:

I documented a full solution that worked for me here:

- [BlackBerry - use own JAR file in own project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9978353/383414)

In my case, I was importing my own JAR file, and I needed to set that project's build type to be a `MIDLET`. Setting it as `LIBRARY` or `APPLICATION` caused problems.